# Spring Integration - Convert Service Activator with Java Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I try to convert the "Hello World example" from Spring Integration samples (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/helloworld) from XML, to Java Configuration, (so with the `@Configuration` annotation).

The configuration class looks like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class BasicIntegrationConfig{

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel inputCHannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel outputChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel= "inputChannel", outputChannel= "outputChannel" )
    public MessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
        MessageHandler mh =  new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("Message payload: " + message.getPayload());
            }
        };
        return mh;
    }
}
```

To test it, I use the `main()` supplied from sample project :

```
DirectChannel fileChannel = applicationContext.getBean("inputChannel", DirectChannel.class);
QueueChannel outputChannel = applicationContext.getBean("outputChannel", QueueChannel.class);
System.out.println("********** SENDING MESSAGE");
fileChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("test"));
System.out.println(outputChannel.receive(0).getPayload());
```

I see in the console "Message payload: test", but unfortunately, I don't receive the message on the outputchannel (I have a `NullPointerException` on `outputChannel.receive(0)`.
Do you have an idea why the Service Activator does not send the message to the output channel?

Comment: You have a typo: `inputCHannel` (capital H) twice in your class `BasicIntegrationConfig` but you call it `inputChannel` (lower-case h) in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you Jesper, indeed, but in my code it was correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MessageHandler` returns `void`.

You need to subclass `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Gary, it works perfectly after switching to :

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel= "inputChannel")
    public AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
        AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler  mh = new AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler() {
            @Override
            protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message) {
                String payload= (String)message.getPayload();
                return "Message Payload : ".concat(payload);
            }
        };
        mh.setOutputChannelName("outputChannel");
        return mh;
    }
```

As a side note, I had to remove the `output channel` attribute in `@ServiceActivator` annotation, and put it in method body instead (Bean Validation Exception if not).